# Load custom css depending on url query string and maintain user on that query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, query-string

Is it possible to have a custom css class for a page accessed by a custom query string? And to maintain that query string while the user is navigating inside the website?

For example, users from `example.com/page123?&example1` will have a custom css like

```
.example1 {
display: block
}
```

and users accessing `example.com/page123` will see

```
.example1 {
display: none
}
```

But if the user is already in page123, and it goes to page1234, the query string will persist and the class example1 with display: block will also be applied. Just to mention, I'm using Wordpress, and PHP, jQuery or Plugins are allowed.

Comment: If you are using php you can achieve this pretty easily.

Comment: How? I'm using wordpress

Comment: Someone needs to mark this as not a duplicate. The link to the supposedly "duplicate" thread is something completely different. That thread is based on changing the color of the link based on href value, this is changing css based on the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in php pretty easily...

This code will get everything after the last slash

```
$page= substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

Put your url into the variable $url and then you can just have a php check like:

```
<?php 
if($page = "page123")
   echo css file
else
   //Echo another css file
?>
```

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear on my first question, please check my edit to see if you can understand..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class in body using javascript and after use a css property inside different bodies

```
var url = window.location.href;
var param = url.splice('?')[1]; // Get your class "ex example1"

$('body').addClass(param);

var urlparam = "?" + param;
//Redirecting
window.location = "your normal url" + urlparam;
```

css:

```
body.example1 div.foo {
   display: none
}

body.example2 div.foo {
   display: block
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And now how is it possible to keep this query string while the user is surfing the website?

Comment: checkout the edits

Comment: Where do I tell my query string "?example1"? And example 2 is what what class? The original one?

Comment: just another class to exemple, you can use withou the example class, put it before the class one, the different configs will overlap

Answer (score -2):

The key to your issue is that you're using wordpress.  There are 1000s of ways to do this programmatically but the best way with wordpress is a plugin.

There are probably a few.  This one just happened to come up first in the Google search:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/

Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't allow to choose to style a query string